# Change appearance of .txt file editor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, color-scheme

I am using a dark theme for eclipse. When I open a file with .txt extension, the color of the text is black, as well as the background. How can I change the appearence of this .txt file editor? I want to set the text color to white. I am confused by the preferences menu.

Answer (score 4):

I have found it. In the preferences Menu select

1. `General>Appearance>Editors>TextEditors` in the Box named `Appearance color options`
2. select the item `Foreground color`,
3. unmark the checkbox `System Default` and change the **color** to the **desired color**.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be in _Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors_ (not under the _Appearance_ group)

Comment: The version of Eclipse has probably changed since the answer was posted.