# How to edit the text color in .txt files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using the Eclipse dark theme. A lot of my projects, however, require the use of text files for various reasons. Because the text is black, and the editor is black, I cannot read the text in these files if I view them in eclipse. I found where to change colors for things like .c .java etc (preferences->general->appearance->colors and fonts) but I don't see where I can change the text color for .txt files.

Is it possible to make .txt files readable in Eclipse's dark theme? Or do I need to switch back to the white theme?

I found an answer online which said to follow the path (General>Appearance>Editors>TextEditors) but I don't have this path. I assume the options hierarchy must have been updated in the last major release of Eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461047/change-appearance-of-txt-file-editor-in-eclipse

Comment: @MC10 I saw that, but I don't see that same hierarchy of options on my version of Eclipse. I assumed it must have changed with the new version of Eclipse.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be in _Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors_

Comment: @tobias_k I've been there as well but I can't find an option for text color.

Comment: Well, which version of Eclipse _are_ you using?

Comment: @tobias_k Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1) - I just looked it up and saw that there's a Mars release. Whoops. I'll install that.

Comment: I'm using Luna and changed it to Dark theme. The font for a .txt file isn't black for me. Weird, hopefully the update works for you.

Comment: I am using Luna, too. The option should be there. Note that _Editors_ is _not_ under _Appearance_ but directly under _General_.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Eclipse Luna. Upgrading to Eclipse Mars fixed my issue.